# How to add mini info to an Eclipse Project Folder?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

As you can see, in Eclipse I created a new Android Project then i noticed a good thing.
**gen** folder has a mini info about its purpose. *See red colored area.*

1. Can i add manually this type of info to other folders? If yes, how?
2. Second question is, if we can't do it, how auto generated project can do it?

[image: Eclipse Project]

Comment: AFAIK, We cannot do that from within eclipse, this is internal feature of eclipse and it identifies project structure and comments accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (in an easy way that is). You have to write you own Eclipse plugin to do that. Check [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html) on how to do it.

Comment: why we can't? is it a security reason?

Comment: I don't think so, I think it's more about a not so important feature. Eclipse already has a lot of plugins.